# Sparql MULTIPLE not exists condition

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm executing a Sparql query that returns all the URIs where the keyword `apple` does not belong to a specific subclass `Species`

```
select distinct ?s 
where 
{ 
?s a owl:Thing . ?s rdfs:label ?label . 
filter(langmatches(lang(?label), 'en')) ?label bif:contains '"apple"' . 
filter not exists {?s rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf* dbo:Species } 
}
```

I want to include more subclasses. I want to include MANY subclasses, so I want filter out like so:

`filter not exists {?s rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf* dbo:Species` AND `filter not exists {?s rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf* dbo:Organisation` AND `filter not exists {?s rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf* dbo:SomeOtherSubclass`

How do I chain MULTIPLE ANDs together?

Comment: either inline data by `VALUES` as shown in the answer below or `filter not exists {?s rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf* ?cls . filter in (cls1, cls2, ...)}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
FILTER NOT EXISTS { 
   VALUES ?clazz { dbo:Species dbo:Organisation dbo:SomeOtherSubclass } 
   ?s rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf* ?clazz. 
 }
```

No guarantees on how well this performs though.

Comment: Thank you sir! It worked. Not worried about the performance. It is a lot better than scraping stuff as HTML and doing a linear search